# Software development methodology - Competitive Development

Tags: agile, methodology

What is the name of the software development methodology in which:

- Multiple teams work on the same feature in isolation

At the end of the sprint, each team presents solution and:

- The best solution wins and is accepted
- The losing solutions are dropped

Comment: I believe that's known as OMGWTF.

Comment: Now that is a funny comment.

Answer (score 2):

That premise is the subject of a 1997 novel by Tom DeMarco, titled [The Deadline: A Novel About Project Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0932633390).